# Laptop that can drive an external 4k monitor

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, monitors, video-adapters

Hoping to find a laptop that can drive an external 4k monitor. I actually don't need it for gaming. I just have a 43" tv mounted above my desk and I want to take advantage of the real estate (e.g. open a lot of documents at once). Unfortunately, most laptops don't specify the max external resolution. For example, this one:

https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Lenovo-Z50-75-Signature-Edition-Laptop/productID.2740240000?tduid=(59f623e84acc587526a4aad32faec6e0)(256380)(2459594)(rtNvgWs52OI-h4mz.t3J1Y5mFvpGm_15Dw)()

and this one:

http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/inspiron-17-5759-laptop/pd?oc=cai175w7ph2404c2&dgc=BF&cid=22740&lid=4279737&acd=12309198376456750&ven1=12715229-934410-&ven3=570802990891566004

Or another recommendation (in the low price range)?

Comment: As far as the Lenovo [Product PDF](http://psref.lenovo.com/syspool%5CSys/PDF/Lenovo%20Laptops/Lenovo%20Z50/Lenovo_Z50-70-75_Platform_Specifications.pdf) If you look under the section labeled "Graphics" it seems that the max external via the HDMI 1.4 is 1900x1200 @ 60hz.

Comment: @NZKshatriya That's for the Z50-70, not Z50-75, I think.

Comment: ya know, you got me on that one.  Info on max external resolution is really hard to find, you would think they would offer information on that as a lot of people use laptops as desktop replacements.  What is your budget for a system, as far as top of the mark?

Comment: I'd like to keep it under $300, and I don't need a laptop. My set up is a 4k monitor and a closet nearby where I will hide the hardware. So I will also need a BT mouse and keyboard.

Comment: If you have a system already, you can upgrade the GPU to something really inexpensive along the lines of these:  [EVGA Geforce GT 710](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814487219)     /    [SAPPHIRE NITRO Radeon R7 360](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814202196)      Would that work for you?  There are less expensive cards as well.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Thank you! How do I know that my motherboard is compatible with the graphics card?

Comment: What brand/model system do you have?  Also, if you run a system information utility like [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) it will give you information on your system, such as what motherboard you have, ram, etc.  If your system is PCIe 1.0 or 2.0, a PCIe 3.0 card will still run, it will just reduce its throughput to the PCIe version you are running.

Comment: @AntonGovorilov  can you add this to the question so that your title's not so misleading?

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw in a recommendation for the [Dell XPS line of products](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-9360-laptop/pd?ref=PD_OC).  These are super elegant machines with great specs.  I especially like the "Infinity Edge Display."

As for your requirement of supporting 4K displays:

[image]

Every XPS model, from the 13" entry level to the top of the line 15" all have the same display support, so your options here are plentiful.

Comment: It is definitely awesome that these machines can do this, but it sucks they have to do it through the thunderbolt port so that you have to get one or two adapters to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I like the cut of this Lenovo's jib: the **[Ideapad 310 80ST0005US](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834331565)**. With one of the new quad core Bristol Ridge APUs inside and support for HDMI 2.0, it definitely supports 4K screens. Likely to also be a relatively performative bit of hardware, as well.

It's a bit pricey, but perhaps now that you know you need HDMI 2.0 to be certain of 4K, you can find it, or something like it, cheaper elsewhere.

Comment: So what tells you that it supports 4k external resolution?

Comment: @AntonGovorilov I know because the iGPU supports it: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-A10-Series%20A10-9600P.html and because that is an explicit part of the HDMI 2.0 specification.

Comment: Ah, I'm beginning to figure it out. So what is "A10-9600P": is it the motherboard, the CPU or the combination of everything?

Comment: @AntonGovorilov It is the combination CPU/GPU, called an APU in this case (Accelerated Processing Unit) because it has an iGPU in it in addition to the standard four CPU cores.